# Send input to console applications in Node Webkit

Tags: console, node-webkit

is there a way to send input and receive output from console programs using Node Webkit?

I tried searching the net but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if you can do it in node.js, you should be able to do it in node-webkit.  For example, to receive output from the 'ls' command and print it to console.log, you could do this:

```
exec('ls', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout)
});
```

Of course, you'd want to do some error handling as well in real life.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you put a custom application in place of `ls` ?

Comment: That should be no problem, as long as it's in your path.